# ERD... Is this a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I have 2 tables below. `USERS` can have 1 or more `PROJECTS`. The `PROJECTS` table references the `USERS` table in a number of fields where the referenced `user_id`'s can be either all the same or different. Is this a many to many relationship?

```
table: USERS
------------
user_id pk,
user_firstname,
user_lastname

table: PROJECTS
---------------
project_id pk,
created_by fk references USERS,
project_manager fk references USERS,
dev_lead fk references USERS
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  You have three foreign keys in `PROJECTS` that all happen to refer to the same table `USERS`, but none of them is a many-to-many relationship.

Each project can have ONE created_by, ONE project manager, and ONE dev lead.

A many-to-many relationship would be a situation where each project could have many dev leads and each dev lead could manage many projects.  In such a situation, you'd have a third table (e.g., `PROJECT_DEV_LEAD_USERS`) to hold the relationship.